# Parsing Large CSV File Where I Only Need The Values in 2 Columns (Java)

Tags: csv

I have the following part of a CSV File with 7 columns (see first line) and I want to put the dates (1st column) as the keys in a TreeMap and the Adj Close values (7th column) as the mapped values in the TreeMap:

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close

7/1/2011,132.09,134.1,131.78,133.92,202370700,133.92
6/30/2011,131.14,132.18,130.71,131.97,223496600,131.97
6/29/2011,130.2,130.93,129.63,130.72,244295500,130.72
6/28/2011,128.45,129.63,128.27,129.61,165556300,129.61

In an earlier part of the assignment, I only had to put the Open values (2nd column) as the mapped values (the dates were the keys) in a TreeMap. I used Scanner for this and my code is below:

```
TreeMap<String, String> loadPriceData(String fileName) throws Exception 
{
     TreeMap<String, String> prices = new TreeMap<String, String>();//create prices map
     Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
     fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]+");// use comma as delimiter
     while(fileScanner.hasNext()) //condition detects comma
     {
         prices.put(fileScanner.nextLine(),fileScanner.nextLine());
     }
     return prices;
}
```

But this seems only good for 2 column CSV data. If I need the mapped values in the 7th column, what's an efficient way to go about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use an open source library for the parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work. The delimiter pattern is not correct. If you look at the contents of your map, you will see that instead of having date-price mappings, you only have one strange mapping.

Instead of using a Scanner, a simpler way is to read the file line-by-line, split each line on comma and put the fields you need into the map.

For example:

```
public TreeMap<String, String> loadPriceData(String fileName) throws IOException  {
     TreeMap<String, String> prices = new TreeMap<String, String>();// create prices map
     BufferedReader in = null;
     try {
         in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
         String line;

         //read each line in the csv file
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

             //split line on comma
             String[] fields = line.split(",");

             //put the first and second fields into the map
             prices.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
         }
         return prices;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw e;
     } finally {
         if (in != null) {
             try {
                 in.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {// ignore
             }
         }
     }
}
```

If you are using **Java 7**, you can make use of the *try-with-resources* statement:

```
public TreeMap<String, String> loadPriceData(String fileName) throws IOException  {
     TreeMap<String, String> prices = new TreeMap<>();// create prices map
     try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName}),
                                                  Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
         String line;

         //read each line in the csv file
         while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

             //split line on comma
             String[] fields = line.split(",");

             //put the first and second fields into the map
             prices.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
         }
         return prices;
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have gotten the data I needed into my TreeMap. However, I'm puzzled as to why my TreeMap is not already in the sorted order shown in my CSV file after I parse the CSV file using your first suggestion. If you take a look at the top few lines of my CSV file above, the dates are descending. But when I use an iterator to iterate through my TreeMap and print the keys and values, it comes out in a completely different order. Do you have any ideas for why this is happening? Also it seems the headers in the first line are also not in my TreeMap. Thanks.

Comment: The map is sorted according to the "natural ordering" of its keys. Your keys are strings, so the map will perform string comparison in order to sort them. The keys are returned in ascending order. If you want them in descending order, you can call `prices.descendingMap()`. The header is in the map, with key=Date, value=Open.

Comment: OK now I think I understand. The string comparison is from left to right, so that's why 1/10/1994 comes first, then 1/10/1995 and so on in the output. So I guess need to parse the dates so that key order is 1/10/1994, 1/11/1994, 1/12/1994 etc., though this seems a bit tricky because you're not allowed to change the "natural ordering"? Anyways, I got rid of the headers by using an if condition to skip over the header line. Thanks.

Comment: @dogbane what if those columns which i want is having comma within the name of those fields.